# Error Message: E: The package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: ppa, archive

I receive the message below:

```
sudo apt-get install package-name
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I have already tried -install , -update, etc.

Comment: Try installing a newer version of `linux-image-extra`. Which versions are available to you can be seen from `apt-cache policy linux-image-extra-*`.

Comment: I'm not even sure how I would go about that. I need a line to line.

Comment: never mind, please follow Karel's suggestions.

Comment: Karel's suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? What is the output of `apt policy linux-image-extra*`?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I followed another string recently that suggested to use dpkg  coupled with --force. I think the main issue was having a System Manager Update installed. But the problem is solved. I cannot find the link to the suggestion.